# Defining FomGroup using object definitions

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible natively to define a ReactiveForm group using object definitions instead of defining directly in the component?

I meam, instead:

```
formEdit = this.fb.group({
  id: [null],
  userName: [{ value: null, disabled: true }],
  email: [null, Validators.required],
  name: [null, Validators.required],
  nickName: [null, Validators.required]
});
```

use something like:

```
formEdit = this.fb.group(User);
```

and in the User class, I decorate its properties accordingly.

### update

It will be nice to define decorators in the User class, like this:

```
export class User {
    @required
    @disabled
    userName: string;

    @required
    @minValue(0)
    @maxValue(100)
    price: number;

   ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [**Dynamic Forms**](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) in Angular.

According to the Angular Guide:

> Building handcrafted forms can be costly and time-consuming, especially if you need a great number of them, they're similar to each other, and they change frequently to meet rapidly changing business and regulatory requirements.
>
> It may be more economical to create the forms dynamically, based on metadata that describes the business object model.

You'll have to do some initial setup which could be time-consuming. But once that is taken care of, the creation of forms is pretty straight-forward.

The documentation that is linked above has a great guide and use-cases where building a dynamic form would make sense.

### UPDATE:

If you don't want to change your Template, then you'll have to create a method that could generate the FormGroup for you based on the configuration that you provide. But again, this will require a configuration instead of a POJO.

If you're still interested, you can get a start here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  sampleObject = {
    id: { value: null },
    userName: { value: null, disabled: true },
    email: { value: null, validators: [Validators.required] },
    name: { value: null, validators: [Validators.required] },
    nickName: { value: null, validators: [Validators.required] }
  };

  formGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup(this.createFormGroup(this.sampleObject));
    console.log(this.formGroup);
  }

  private createFormGroup(config) {
    const group = {};
    for(let key in config) {
      const itemConfig = config[key];
      group[key] = new FormControl(itemConfig.value, itemConfig.validators);
    }
    return group;
  }

}
```

**NOTE:** This won't work in all the scenarios. If you want it to work in all cases, you'll have to improve the `createFormGroup` method accordingly.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-form-group-generation-based-on-js-object?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: It´s interesting, but I want to keep my .html the same as today, just change the formgroup initialization.

Comment: It´s a possibility, but I´m looking for a solution using decorators in the model class, like my update above.